# How can be a realm has multiple principals in shiro?

Tags: realm, shiro, principal

There's a method of PrincipalCollection : `Collection fromRealm(String realmName)` , but how can be one login assign muiltiple `Principal`s to a realm?  Thank you

Comment: Please provide some more info related to your question. A code example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could create a realm to log into with certificates, so you could have a cert based principal, but you might have a username principal as well.  Or you could have a custom principal that puts both of these attributes in a single object.